# Inflate a custom view from XML, then set her height and witdh programmatically

Tags: android, xml, custom-view, android-inflate, layoutparams

I'm loosing myself in an custom size View problem since a couple of days. After some long research, I finally decide to ask your help... please ! T_T

In my app, I created a custom View with the XML *calendrieradmin_day.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/CalendrierAdmin_Day_Event_TableRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!--  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CalendrierAdmin_Day_Event_TextView_Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />-->
</TableRow>
```

For now, it is a simple TableRow, but I'll need to add some other things in the future. (The commented TextView, for example).

I made three classes for using it : **Row**, **EventRow** and **EmptyRow**. **Row** is abstract and **EventRow** and **EmptyRow** inherit of **Row**. Also, **Row** inherit of **TableRow**.

I want to add several **EventRow** and **EmptyRow** in a **TableLayout** and I need to resize them dynamically.

In the constructor method of EmptyRow and EventRow, I call an init() method. Here the one of **EventRow** :

```
private void init(Context c, TableLayout root) {    
    root = (TableLayout)LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.calendrieradmin_day_event, root, true);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) root.getLayoutParams();

    lp.height = getHeightOfMinute() * getDuree();
    lp.width = getTheWidth();

    /*
    Some other stuff
    ...
    ...
    */

    this.setLayoutParams(lp);

    root.addView(this);

    setOnClickListener(this);
    setOnLongClickListener(this);
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work as excepted. The **EventRow** is not showed.

*root* is my **TableLayout** I pass in the constructor. *getHeightOfMinute()* and *getDuree()* work correctly and give me the right sizes. I used to use the *inflate()* method like *inflate(R.layout.calendrieradmin_day_event, null, false)* and it worked fine, but Eclipse gave me a warning, telling me I shouldn't pass *null* as the *RootView* argument. Although everything worked fine, I begun to search another solution and this is where I gone so far...

I used the *setMinimumHeight()* and *setMinimumWidth()* method to rezise my **EventRow** and **EmptyRow**. It works, but I think there is a better way to do that. I tried A LOT of solutions but I messed up ! I think there is something I still not catched about the functioning of *inflate()* and/or **LayoutParams**.

Could you help me ? Thanks in advance !

*Please tell me if you need more piece of Source code.*

PS: Sorry for the bad english, I'm french.

Comment: Viliktùr did you get anywhere with this?

I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Yes, but I changed a lot of things... :-)

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working myself yesterday, having to Override both onLayout and onMeasure.

Comment: I manage to make it works by using some LinearLayout and the _weight_ properties. Do you want me to be more explicit ? I'll be glad if you could explain me your own method, I'm sure it will be useful one day or another.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed it, but a lot of things have been changed.

First, I drop the **TableLayout** and **TableRow**. Now it is simply some **LinearLayout**.

*calendrieradmin_day.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/CalendrierAdmin_Day_Event_LinearLayout_Container"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/CalendrierAdmin_Day_Event_TextView_Name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/background_event_full"
    android:gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the *init()* method :

```
private void init(Context c, LinearLayout root) {   
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.calendrieradmin_day_event, root, false);
    TextView name = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.CalendrierAdmin_Day_Event_TextView_Name);


    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, duree);        
    container.setLayoutParams(lp);

    name.setLayoutParams(lptv);


    name.setText(e.getNom());

    root.addView(container);

    name.setOnClickListener(this);
    name.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}
```

Pay attention to the **LayoutParams** lp (It's a LinearLayout.LayoutParams). *duree* is the duration of my event, in minutes.

My **EventRow** are intended to be in an another **LinearLayout**, *llEvents*. It contains all the events for one day, so 1440 minutes (60 x 24). As a result, the weightSum of *llEvents* is 1440.

I dropped the **EmptyRow** and the **Row** class to. I just add some empty **LinearLayout** to llEvents for the free time schedules, with there duration as *weight*.

***It's REALLY important to presize a "0" height in the LayoutParams***

Hope It will help someone ;-) !